# How do you make an image as a link

Tags: android, eclipse, image, hyperlink

I know how to make a Button as a link but I don't know how to make as below as a link?

```
<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/agoda" />
```

.......................................................................................

Comment: use `setOnClickListener` for your view,

Comment: you might first need to use `setClickable(true)` for your view